# Sort data by keys on the map

Tags: java

I want to sort my data based on the ID key in the below code. Is there a solution?

```
List<Map<String, Object>> baseList = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("ID", i);
    map.put("Name", "aa");
    baseList.add(map);
}
System.out.println(baseList);
```

Comment: This code already adds each map to the list in ID order. Are you getting a different result than you expected?

Comment: Collections.sort(baseList, Comparator.comparingInt(o -> ((int) o.get("ID"))));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your sample code, the list is already sorted by `ID`, but if that is just sample input:

Since you want to sort the list, your can just use the `sort` method and specifiy that the ID in the map is supposed to be the sort key:

```
baseList.sort(Comparator.comparing(m -> (Integer)m.get("ID")));
```

Since that `Map` returns `Object`, you have to cast the value behind "ID" to `Integer` since `Object` itself does not implement `Comparable`.